# How do I send error message from server to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm making some requests from my express server, and I'm wondering how I can pass an error message to the client side.  I want to be able to see the error message when I console log from the client as well as from the server, but I'm not sure how to relay this message back to the client to make that possible.

Here is an example of a request from my server.js file

```js
app.get('/assign*', (request, response) => {
    var baseurl = 'https://OURACC.nocrm.io/api/v2/'
    var apikey = crmkey;

    var pathname = request.url; // retrieves the requested pathname (ie, /crm/path)
    pathname = pathname.split('?');
    pathname = pathname[0].split('/')
    var parameters = request.query.params;
    var path = pathname[2]; // gets request path for the crm

   var lead_id = parameters.lead_id
    var user_id = parameters.user_id

    var params = {
        user_id: user_id
    }

    if(path === 'leads'){

            axios.post(baseurl + path + '/' + lead_id + '/assign',
                params
            ,{
                headers: {'X-API-KEY': apikey, content_type: "json", accept: "application/json"} 
            }).then(function(res){
                response.send(res.data);
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log("ERROR in /assign/leads/{id}/assign" + error);
            })

    }

})
```

This is what the call to this request looks like client side

```js
 $.get('/assign/leads', {params: data}).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

I've tried this server side

```js
response.send(error)
```

but this doesn't return me anything client side like I was expecting.

I'm sure this is something simple, but I couldn't find much online about it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, just put `response.send(yourErrorMessage)` in the catch block

Comment: I feel like I tried this and nothing showed up in the console client side, but I can try again.

Comment: @Michael ya, I just noticed you did. Debug your code to make sure that the "respond" variable you have there is the correct one

Comment: @Michael i see that you want to get params from the request. I am not a pro at express so I dont know if you are doing it correctly. Visit this link https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html and go to the params sections. They have something like app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) { res.send(req.params) }) just swap in the error message into the res

Comment: The issue was because I wasn't doing response.send(error.message).  By doing this I'm now getting the error message client side.

Comment: Great! Glad to have been some sort of help :)

Comment: @Michael I am sorry, I should have noticed this, yes, you had to get the error message out of error. Error is an object so if you wanted to send the whole error object you should have used JSON.stringify() like respondse.send(JSON.stringify(error));

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify response code. For example:

```
res.status(400);
res.send('None shall pass');
```